# Trigger the default action of an event

Tags: jquery

In an event handler, how can I trigger the default actions. That is, is there something that does the opposite of `.event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: You can trigger an event using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this solved?
I have a simple autocomplete box for my form and I'd like a mouse click on one of the items to trigger a simulated "enter" keypress on the input (which should submit the form). I know I can use other methods to find the form and submit, but I was wondering if what I want to do it indeed doable?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use bind function to handle any events to prevent default actions

```
$('#id').bind('click', function() {
  //your action goes here 
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Then don't use `event.preventDefault();`  and use `return true`

Comment: Don't work for what I need it for: http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/76/ (I want to simulate a TAB keypress.)

Comment: Saying just don't do what you want to do is not an answer.